# Error: Unexpected token ] in JSON at position 652

Tags: angular

my project it isn't running anymore when i try to run ng serve i got this error

> Error: Unexpected token ] in JSON at position 652
>       at Function.fromConfigPath (C:\Users\Administrateur\Desktop\CustemerManagementFront\node_modules@angular\cli\models\config\config.js:89:19)
>       at Function.fromProject (C:\Users\Administrateur\Desktop\CustemerManagementFront\node_modules@angular\cli\models\config.js:67:46)
>       at Object. (C:\Users\Administrateur\Desktop\CustemerManagementFront\node_modules@angular\cli\commands\build.js:10:35)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
>       at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
>       at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)

the file angular-cli.json

```
  {
      "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
      "project": {
        "name": "custemer-management"
      },
      "apps": [
        {
          "root": "src",
          "outDir": "dist",
          "assets": [
            "assets",
            "favicon.ico"
          ],
          "index": "index.html",
          "main": "main.ts",
          "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
          "test": "test.ts",
          "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
          "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
          "prefix": "app",
          "styles": [
            "styles.css",
            "src/../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
            "../node_modules/ng2-toastr/bundles/ng2-toastr.min.css",

          ],
          "scripts": [
            "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
          ],
          "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
          "environments": {
            "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
            "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
          }
        }
      ],
      "e2e": {
        "protractor": {
          "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
        }
      },
      "lint": [
        {
          "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
          "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
        },
        {
          "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
          "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
        },
        {
          "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
          "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
        }
      ],
      "test": {
        "karma": {
          "config": "./karma.conf.js"
        }
      },
      "defaults": {
        "styleExt": "css",
        "component": {}
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us the file in question, `.angular-cli.json`?

Comment: Just follow the three steps in https://v4.angular.io/guide/quickstart to get started with the project

Comment: i already have angular project i can't run it anymore @cobra

Comment: i add it below check plz @Vlad274

Comment: You're not showing all the error message, there should be more error than that. Also it could be that your ng version is newer than your project's. `angular-cli.json` is quite old.

Comment: i added all error below check plz @penleychan

Comment: Try reinstalling angular cli to a specific version for your project. Your angular version would be < 6.

Comment: what do you mean by _my project it isn't running anymore_? what did you changed before it stopped working?

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove trailing commas at the end of `"../node_modules/ng2-toastr/bundles/ng2-toastr.min.css",` and `"../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",`.

JSON doesn't allow it.

Answer (score 0):

As @pindev said, the trailing commas at the mentioned lines are the problem, as they cause invalid JSON format.

If you modify the file yourself, you should make sure it has a valid JSON format. There are many JSON validators online, which tell you if it has a valid format and if not, it shows you where are the errors.